# Formatting bibliography with biblatex for harvard style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

I'm trying to print a bibliography for my masters thesis using bibLatex, however there are some discrepancies with the setup I'm using. for instance, the book bibliography entry prints the location before the place of publication, when it should be the opposite, the journal entry puts the journal in double quotations instead of a single quotations, etc.

I'm pretty new to Latex and I've been all over to start formatting my bibliography, so excuse me if I have made some mistakes in my setup but here it is

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
   style=authoryear,
   uniquename=false,
   hyperref=auto,
   date=year,
   natbib=true,
   url=false,
   isbn=false]{biblatex}    

\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]

\begin{document}
\include{Cover}
\begin{singlespace}  
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\include{Abstract}
\clearpage
\end{singlespace}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{introduction}
\cleardoublepage
\include{literature_review}
\cleardoublepage
\include{methodology}
\cleardoublepage
\include{technical}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{References}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{document}
```

I am using overleaf. On a side note I would welcome any resource that help me understand latex more, most of the resources I came across are either explains beginner knowledge it has become trivial for me now, or are too advanced for me to follow. thanks

Comment: Note that "Harvard style" only refers to a broad class of citation/bibliography styles (namely author-year styles). The generic term "Harvard style" does not uniquely define a single citation/bibliography style. (For example, APA style and Chicago's author-date style could said to be a Harvard styles, as can be the many Harvard flavoured styles recommended by English universities.) ...

Comment: ... So we can only help you achieve the style you need if you tell us exactly what needs to be changed. Please remember that question on TeX.SX should ideally be about a single issue only, so please split up the things you need to change into separate questions. I'm sure many of your question will already have been asked and answered elsewhere (but I fully admit that previous questions can be hard to find, so please do not let this be a reason to discourage you from asking these questions!). A first point of contact for `biblatex` questions is the lovely https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/.

Comment: `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]` is wrong. `\defbibheading` takes two mandatory arguments. The call is missing the actual definition of the heading. Remove that line and change `\chapter{References}\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]` to `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title=References]`. The `biblatex` option `hyperref=auto,` is the default and can be dropped. `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` should be `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I did go through a lot of posts to try and fix my issues, however they are very specific, and I admit the commands go over my head. The guide you provided is great, I'm sure it will help. after posting I waded through the biblatex manual and I managed to adjust the issues in the question, although I'm still struggling with other issues. I will take your advise however, and divide the issues into separate posts.

Comment: Since there is no well-defined "Harvard style" the question cannot be answered as-is. But I think it can reasonably be seen as asking for general `biblatex` advice, which would make it a perfect duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/. If you have more specific issues, just ask new questions.